# Go a folder back in directory path

Tags: php, laravel

It would seem quite obvious, use `/../` but for some odd reason it doesn't work. When I use the following require it won't work properly,

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then when I check the path on php it says this,

> Warning: require(/var/www/laravel/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Am I missing something?

Comment: does `/var/www/laravel/vendor/autoload.php` exist on your server?

Comment: `$ composer install` ;)

Comment: @MajidLaissi nope, my bad, sorry. I should've checked better.

Comment: Also for future reference [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) will move a path string up one directory.